# Read file by bits c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

i have binary file as input and i need to read it simple by bits. If i wanted to read file by characters i would use this:

```
    ifstream f(inFile, ios::binary | ios::in);
    char c;
    while (f.get(c)) {
        cout << c;
    }
```

Output of this code is sequence of characters, what i need is sequence of 1 and 0. Function get() return next character and i could not find any ifstream function that would return next bit.

Is there any similar way how to achieve it ?

Thank anyone for help.

Comment: Best you can do is a byte (char) at a time.

Comment: Just read characters and convert their values to binary.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't just read file bit by bit.
So, you should use something like this:

```
ifstream f(inFile, ios::binary | ios::in);
char c;
while (f.get(c))
{
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) // or (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)  if you want reverse bit order in bytes
        cout << ((c >> i) & 1);
}
```